# Make a drop down menu required depending the selection of previous drop down

Tags: javascript, dropdown, required

I have a successful piece of javascript that when selecting from a drop down menu makes a text box or text area required. It however does not work with another drop down box. Any help would be appreciated.

Example: When selecting "Collection" from the first drop down, the drop down "Number_of_parcels" (which is always visible), becomes required. Nothing changes when selecting "Delivery" etc. I am stumped and any help would be appreciated.

```
JAVASCRIPT
function selection()
{    
 var cat = document.getElementById('Collection_Delivery').value;    
    if (cat == "Collection") {
        if (document.getElementById("Number_of_parcels").value == "") {
            alert('This must be completed');
            return false;
        }

    }
    return true;
}


HTML first drop down:
<select name="Collection_Delivery" id="Collection_Delivery"     onChange="selection()">
      <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">-</option>
      <option value="Delivery">Delivery</option>
      <option value="Collection">Collection</option>
      <option value="Collection and Delivery">Collection &amp Delivery</option>
    </select>

HTML second drop down:
<select name="Number_of_parcels" id="Number_of_parcels">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Please select</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>

<input type="submit" value="Send" onClick="return checkForm(this.form);selection()" name="myButton">
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please be careful with  how you tag questions here; [tag:java] is as similar to [tag:javascript] as _ham_ is to _hamster_.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I am right here aren't I with the tag Javascript. This is scripting not programming.

Comment: OK, I have solved it, by removing selected="selected" it worked.